# If I am making a background color for a paragraph and i want the lines to separate what do I do

Tags: html, css

I haven't tried much but i want it to highlight the text in a certain color but not solid I want it to be spaced between lines

```
.t2{
    position:fixed;
    font-size:20px; 
    top:80px;
    background-color:#00ff00;
}
```

Comment: What is the question - where are the lines - where is the background - where is highlight text - where is not solid - also where you want your spaced line.

Comment: I would rec-emend that to get some answers to your question read here [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks :)

Comment: Put your text in a `span`, apply `background-color` to the `span`. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) to highlight text.

```css
.t2{
    position:fixed;
    font-size:20px; 
    top:80px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #00ff00, 0 0 5px #00ff00, 0 0 5px #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="t2">This is some text<br/>
This is the next line of text</div>
```

You can wrap your text in a `span` to make a background that spans each line instead of the entire element.

```css
.t2{
    position:fixed;
    font-size:20px; 
    top:80px;
}

.t2 > span {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="t2">
<span>This is some text<br/>
This is the next line of text
</span></div>
```

Comment: That helps a lot but is there anyway to make it a solid color

Comment: @JaysonEllis What do you mean by solid? Spanning the entire line?

Comment: not have the entire paragraph solid but have a solid color and have white spaces in between lines

Comment: @JaysonEllis I've updated my answer. Is that the effect you are looking for?

Comment: Yes thank you for your time

Comment: @JaysonEllis No problem.